# PHP Arrays and stdClass objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project to get the names of an array. 
The arrays seem to be multidimensional, with the added bonus of being a stdclass Object. I am trying to select a key from the provided array but seem to have no luck selecting them.

```
echo($response->array[shoecompany]->array[1]->name);
```

from the information here

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [shoe] => shoemaker
    [shoecompany] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shoenumber] => 1
                    [name] => Blank

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shoenumber] => 2
                    [name] => demo
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shoenumber] => certificate
                    [name] => certofsale

                )

        )

)
```

Nothing i do seems to pull the information i need out of this. Any ways to go about pulling, said information.

Comment: `$response= json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
echo($response['shoecompany'][1]['name']);`

Comment: ksjohn answer should fix your problem. Are you aware there is a typo in your json ? shoecomapny instead of shoecompany.

Comment: yes i am aware lol thank you both

Comment: *`$response->array[shoecompany]`* -- there is no `array` key in `$response`. Read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The arrays seem to be multidimensional, with the added bonus of being a stdclass Object.

Arrays and objects aren't the same things.

I let you learn more about the specifics of both if you are curious.

Regarding access, yous use brackets - '*[]*' - when you want to access something in an array and an arrow - '*->*' - when you want to access an object's property :

```
$array['key'];

$object->property;
```

In your case, since only `$response` and the entries in the entry `showcompany` - I assume it's a typo - are objects, what you should write is :

```
$response->shoecompany[1]->name;
```

Which gives you in practical use :

```
foreach ($response->shoecompany as $val) {
    echo $val->shoenumber, ' : ', $val->name, '<br>'; // Or whatever you want to print, that's for the sake of providing an example
}
```

If it is more convenient for you to handle exclusively arrays, you can also use `get_object_vars()` to convert an object properties to an array :

```
$response = get_object_vars($response);
```

Comment: this helped a lot. would it be easy to attach this to a foreach command?

Comment: To attach what ? For what purpose ?

Comment: foreach shoenumber run a script till dead

Comment: That would be quite simple, have you tried it yet ?

Comment: in the practical use you provided it throws an error i had to change it to

foreach ($response->shoecompany[0] as $val)

it since i had to designate the shoe company would i be able to search for more than one at a time or have to make separate foreach calls for each shoecompany?

Comment: @iDaRkkO There was indeed an error in my code. I accessed $val's entries as if it was an array and didn't check. It's now corrected. Please, use my code. The one in your comment only breaks your foreach by making it useless.

Answer (score 1):

**Code should be like:**

`echo $response->shoecomapny[1]->name;`

In short, to select key inside an object you need to use "->" operator and to select key inside array use "[]".

Comment: its useful to explain why this works if you can, rather than just put corrected code up.

Comment: this was definitely helpful

Comment: @iDaRkkO, If this answer useful to you and it's correct then you should mark it as the correct answer. It will be helpful for others.